# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1922

Tags: identificación-de-término

I think there are 3 entries in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records but it looks like two of them are merged.

To keep this simple to review I can covering the whole set of notes for 1922 in one question as I am not 100% sure where the notes start at stop.

This is the complete note:

[image]

I appreciate that you will not be able to read that image in one go so I will split it.

---

#### First Note

I think (but can't be sure) that this is the first note:
[image]

The reason I think this is the first note is because in the left margin is a o which seems to be used to repeat the year (1922).

Transcription:

> En relacion de xxx de Sr. 1º Jefe Guerra 8 Noviembre y xxx individuo
> al xxx de Fuenta xxx xx al que se incorporo il 29 del mismo.

---

#### Second Note

I believe the second note is a large one and is again related to his employment, this time from 1922 to 1926. But I can't read all the writing or punctuation.

The note (in 3 images):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can't make out a lot of that writing and I do not see a reference to a new soldier number this time. Transcription so far:

> Xxx xxx con premio il xxx en 31 de agosto año marginal, escrito de Sr.
> 1er Jefe esto xxx año por 4 años con el premia de xxx xxx de 2710
> pesetas xxx xxx Gregoria en la R. O. 6 de 11 agosto año 1920 x. XXX
> no. 195 el que la fine xxx las xxx xxx incluir la de xxxdad según xxx
> xxx xxx por provisional xxx la xxx del xxx do R. E. de Director Gral.
> [General] del instituto al principio a regimentó en 1ª de xxx año
> marginal y lo terminara en 31 de agosto año 1926. En relación xxx en
> el [D. O. no. 257](https://bibliotecavirtual.defensa.gob.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=12241) de 16 noviembre so ha xxx admitió en del xxx por
> la autoridad xxx. Y en fuente de xxx xxx xxx finía esta nota el
> inferesanteon los testigos y jefe que xxx
>
> El interesado = firma
>
> El Gral. [General] 2º = firma
>
> El xxx 2º = firma
>
> Comandante de Major = firma

I added a link to the related bulletin (if it is the right one) but I do not know what the pertinent information is in the bulletin.

---

#### Third Note

I believe the third is distinct because of the different hand writing:

[image]

Transcription so far:

> En el puesto de [Fuente Obejuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuente_Obejuna)  finió el año.
>
> El Comandante Major

Thanks for your help is sorting this set of notes for 1922 into something clear and understandable.

---

### Update for note 3

I worked out the location to be **Fuente Obejuna**. Translation:

> The year ended at the Fuente Obejuna post.
>
> The Major Commander

---

### Translations

Based on the hard work provided in the answer I have the following translations:

- Note 1:

> In the list of transfers of Mr. 1st Chief xxx 8 November, this
> individual is assigned to the post of Fuente Obejuna, which he joined
> on the 29th of the same.

- Note 2:

> Fulfilling his commitment, this individual, on 31st August, marginal
> year, requested from his 1st Chief another commitment for 4 years with
> the monthly constancy allowance of 27.50 pesetas as included in the R.
> O. C of 11th August 1920 C. L no. 195, which was accredited to him as
> he fulfilled the conditions foreseen, including usefulness according
> to the medical certificate, until the definitive approval of the S. E.
> of the General Director of the Institute. It began to end on 1
> September of the marginal year and will end on 31 August 1926. In
> relation published in the D. O. no. 257 of 16 November it has been
> definitively admitted by the aforementioned authority. And in proof of
> his conformity, the interested party signs this note with the
> undersigned witnesses and chief.
> The interested party = Miguel Torres Jiménez
> The 2nd Guardsman = Braulio xxx Murillo
> The 2nd Guardsman = Tomás xxx xxx
> Major Commander = José Rodríguez xxx

- Note 3:

> The year ended at the Fuente Obejuna post.
> The Major Commander

I don't know if the associated bulletin uses any of the phrasing we are unsure of?

Comment: Your great-grandfather's name appears [in the list of page 13](https://bibliotecavirtual.defensa.gob.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=12241).

Comment: @gparis Thanks for that observation. I tried to search the PDF and it was not listing his name. Well spotted. Later I will translate the text at the top of that page to see what it says. :)

Comment: The first note's translation seems a copy of the third. It does not translate the original text.

Comment: @RubioRic Apologies. I accidentally copied the 1921 translation.

Comment: Check my last update to complete the missing words in your translation.

Comment: @RubioRic I had issues with DeepL. Broke it down into sentences to do it. Now updated.

Comment: The translation seems ok but this sentence "to the optional but provisional certificate". We have lost the adjective "facultativo" that refers to the certificate being made by a PhD and "provisional" in the Spanish text is related to the commitment being approved in first instance by the 1st Chief but subject to be granted by a higher authority. "provisional" does not apply to the certitificate and it seems to has been translated as "optional".

Comment: @RubioRic  Odd. How would you adjust that bit?

Comment: What about replacing "according to the optional but provisional certificate until" by "according to the medical certificate, until"

Comment: @RubioRic I updated the translation. Thanks.

Comment: For note one I now think the missing word must simply be **fecha**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's begin with the third note that is the easiest

> En el puesto de [**Fuente Obejuna**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuente_Obejuna) finió el año.
>
> El **Comandante Mayor**

---

My suggestions for the first note

> En relación de **traslados** de Sr. 1º Jefe **fecha?** 8 Noviembre **es destinado este** individuo
> al **puesto** de **Fuente Obejuna** al que se incorpor**ó el** 29 del mismo.

---

My suggestions for the second note. A tough one this time!
I've included @gparis and @wimi suggestions too.

> **Cumpliendo su compromiso este individuo** en 31 de agosto año marginal, **solicitó de su**
> 1er Jefe **otro empeño** por 4 años con el premi**o** de **constancia mensual** de **27'50**
> pesetas **como está comprendido**  en la R. O. **C** de 11 agosto año 1920 **C. L**
> nº 195 el que l**e** fue acreditado **por reunir** las **condiciones prevenidas incluso las de utilidad según certificado facultativo pero** provisional **hasta** la **aprobación definitiva** del **S**. E. de Director Gral.
> [General] del Instituto. La principió a **extinguirla** en 1º de **Spbre (Septiembre)** año
> marginal y l**a** terminar**á** en 31 de agosto año 1926. En relacion **publicada** en
> el D. O. nº 257 de 16 noviembre **le** ha **sido admitido** en **definitiva** por la
> **autoridad antes citada**. Y en **prueba** de **su conformidad firma** esta nota el
> **interesado con** los testigos y jefe que **suscriben**
>
> El interesado = Miguel Torres Jiménez
> El Grda. [Guardia] 2º = Braulio xxx Murillo
> El Grda. [Guardia] 2º = Tomás xxx xxx
> Comante. [Comandante] mayor = José Rodríguez Zambrano

Comment: Thanks! I was at a loss! Looking at the page in the bulletin that @gparis mentioned I can see the reference to **C. L. num 195** so I guess that that is one of the xxx values.

Comment: This was really a tough and long one! Let me add some suggestions to complete the transcription: _pesetas como **comprendido**_, _por reunir las **condiciones**_, _aprobación definitiva de **S.E.**_, _José Rodríguez **Zambrano**_. Also _Ocbre_ might be **Spbre**, specially if we consider that both the previous and the current commitment finish at the end of August.

Comment: @gparis Thanks. I have made the changes at my end and will wait for RubioRic accordingly. Then I can tweak the translations. You are right about the month. The page you referred to in the bulletin actually states **1  sepbre 1922.**.

Comment: @gparis I think that all your suggestions make sense. I've updated the answer accordingly. Great contribution!

Comment: Also, I looked at the 1930 note was was the first one you all transcribed for me and I notice: **4 años por reunir las condiciones prevenidas, incluso la de utilidad y como comprendido en la R.O.C.**. So could the missing word be **prevenidas,**? Just a guess.

Comment: To get rid of the last question mark, I would replace **compromo?** with **empeño**.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I've updated my suggestions a pair of times including "prevenidas".

Comment: @wimi Good catch! Updated.

Comment: I found these photos: http://www.fuenteobejuna.com/0.htm