# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1924

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1924 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there is just one entry:

[image]

Transcription so far:

> Según relación de hasta del fecha 9 de octubre año marginal ha sido
> destinado este individuo el puesto de ofícielo alto al que se
> incorporó el 16 de dicho mes y en el finió el año.

I have made an educated guess on the word **ofícielo** and you may see other errors with my attempt. In my word processor it says that **del fecha** should be **de *la* fecha**. But it does look like **del** to me.

Translation so far:

> According to the list dated 9 October of the marginal year, this
> individual has been assigned the post of high clerk to which he joined
> on the 16th of the said month and in which he finished the year.

I am not sure about the word I have chosen! I feel it should be a location but it does not look like the places he has previously served.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Según relación de **traslados** fecha 9 de octubre año marginal ha sido destinado este individuo al puesto de **Ojuelos Altos** al que se incorporó el 16 de dicho mes y en él finió el año.

**Translation**

- According to the list of transfers dated 9 October of the year on the margin, this individual has been assigned to the post of Ojuelos Altos, which he joined on the 16th of the said month and in which he finished the year.

Regarding **[finió](https://dle.rae.es/finir)/[finó](https://dle.rae.es/finar)**: as discussed, **finió** makes more sense because it means "finished" while **finó** means "died" or "consumed itself". However, in all the notes at the end of every year (example [1](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39489/transcribing-spanish-civil-guard-notes-for-1917-note-2-of-2), [2](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39513/transcribing-spanish-civil-guard-notes-for-1922)), it does seem to say "finó", for whichever reason. I have not found any reference to a different meaning of "finar" in the past, so that remains a mystery to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and translation. Concerning the word finio I wonder if it is related to which related word is stressed? For example, “*he* finished” or “finished *the*”. If the latter, then finó might be understood in the sense that the year has died. It is in the past. I don’t really know. Or could it be an archaic use of the word that has changed over time? I also need to look up this location Ojuelos Altos.

Comment: I tried finding a suitable (eg. wiki) entry for **Ojuelos Altos** and did not find anything worthy of note. Located it on Google Maps though.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I had done the same. It looks like no one has been interested in promoting the place. I see now that both "finar" and "finir" are supposed to be intransitive so none of them would fit "nicely"...

Comment: I did find this: https://www.rurality.com/whattodo/ojuelos-altos_es

Comment: Photos: http://www.fuenteobejuna.com/9.htm