# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1925

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1925 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there is just one entry:

[image]

Transcription so far:

> Según relación de traslados de fecha 8 Noviembre año marginal ha sido
> destinado este individuo por su 1er Jefe al puesta de Puente Genil al
> que se incorporó el día 16 del mismo. Y en el que finió el año.

I picked up on the **traslados** word from the [1924](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39523/28260) question as I was not sure before.

Translation so far:

> According to the transfer list dated 8 November of the marginal year,
> this individual has been assigned by his 1st Chief to the Puente Genil
> station, which he joined on the 16th of the same year. And where he
> finished the year.

I am not sure if the last sentence should be a continuation of the previous. Whilst the last sentence looks like it starts with a lower case **y** I can see a distinct **period** before it. Also, it would be more consistent with the other notes if it was all one sentence.

Comment: You've got a minor typo in the Spanish transcription, it should be "puesto" instead of "puesta". And regarding that term, the translation has been "station" in this case but I think that you have used "post" in previous occasions. The rest seems correct.