# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1926 (note 2 of 2)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1926 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there two entries.

This is the second one (I'll continue with other notes as required tomorrow):

[image]

Transcription so far:

> En el B.O. del Cuerpo nº 33 de 20 de Noviembre le ha sido publicado el
> anterior compromiso, prestando sus servicios en el puesto de Puente
> Genil finió el año.
> El Comandante Major

Translation so far:

> In the B.O. of the Corps no. 33 of 20 November, the previous
> commitment was published, and he served in the Puente Genil post at
> the end of the year.
>
> The Major Commander

I notice this translation is also slightly different by saying **at the end of the year** instead of **where he finished the year**.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1926 (note 1 of 2)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39528/28260)

Comment: The word "donde" has been omitted in the Spanish original, it should be "donde finió el año". The sentence is grammatically wrong in Spanish. Also, I've noticed that you tend to transcribe the last sentence as "El Comandante Major" but in Spanish we write MAYOR, like in mayonnaise. ;-P Apart from the missing "where", the translation seems correct.

Comment: @RubioRic Understood and well spotted re: **Mayor**!

Comment: @RubioRic Any thoughts on this one: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39525/28260 ?

Comment: Claramente no pone "finió" sino "finó", supongo que del verbo finar y con el sentido de "terminó", aunque de todos modos no es correcto.