# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1926 (note 1 of 2)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1926 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there two entries. The first one relates to him signing up for another 4 years (1926 - 1930) and as such is similar in terms of content to other notes of this nature.

It is split over two pages in the document:

[image]

[image]

I have done my best to transcribe the note. I also looked at the existing notes to attempt to complete unsure words. This is what I have so far:

> Cumpliendo su compromiso en 31 de Agosto año marginal solicitó y le
> que xxx por su premier Jefe otro por el tiempo de 4 años por xxx las
> condiciones prevenidas, incluso la de este xxx y como comprendido en
> la R. O. C de 11 de Agosto de 1920 ([C. L. no. 195](https://bibliotecavirtual.defensa.gob.es/BVMDefensa/es/publicaciones/verNumero.do?idNumero=47989)) pero en concepto de
> provisional hasta la a fino aprobación al termina del Enero. Sr.
> [Señor] Pto (?) Gral. [General] del Cuerpo. Dicho comprimido da
> servicio en 1º de Septiembre de 1926 y lo terminara en 31 de Agosto de
> 1930, xxx temido durante el mismo el premio mensual de 27’50 pesetas.
> Y en prueba de su conformidad, de firma el interesado la presente xxx
> el Jefe y testigos que suscriben.
> El interesado = Miguel Torres Jiménez
> Testigos =
> El Gua [Guardia] 2º = firma
> El Gua [Guardia] 2º = firma
> El Comandte Major = firma

I refer to a comment made on the answer for the note pertaining to [1930](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/39377/28260) by @gpars:

> Indeed, R.O.C. stands for *Real Orden Circular*. C.L. stands for
> *Colección Legislativa*. The cited decree can be consulted [here](https://bibliotecavirtual.defensa.gob.es/BVMDefensa/es/publicaciones/verNumero.do?idNumero=47989) (page
> 390 of the PDF file).

I see that this reference has appeared several times when my great-grandfather re-enlists. At the moment I have tried to translation the aforementioned decree.

I would be grateful for assistance to complete the transcription so that I can get the translation done. Thanks!

Also, I can't quite make out the word at the top left of the second page (second image). Is it an equivalent of "Continued ..."?

---

#### Translation

Based on the provided answer I have the following translation:

> Fulfilling his commitment on 31st August of the marginal year, he
> requested and was granted by his first Chief another for 4 years as he
> fulfilled the conditions foreseen, including that of usefulness and as
> included in the R. O. C of 11th August 1920 (C. L. no. 195) but on a
> provisional basis until the definitive approval of His Excellency the
> Director General of the Corps. This commitment begins on 1st September
> 1926 and will end on 31st August 1930, during which time he will
> receive a monthly salary of 27.50 pesetas. And in proof of his
> agreement, the interested party signs the present before the
> undersigned Chief and witnesses.
>  The interested party = Miguel
> Torres Jiménez
>  Witnesses =
>  The 2nd Guardsman = Manuel Ruiz
> xxxx
>  The 2nd Guardsman = Alfonso Torres Laguna
>  The Major
> Commander = Juan Egea Urraco
>  All initialled
>  This is a copy
> The Major Commander

Some observations:

1. Is this part of the translation correct?

> … the interested party signs the **present** before …

2. I notice this time better wording. Eg:

> This commitment **begins on** 1st September 1926 and **will end** on 31st
> August 1930, during which time he will receive **a monthly salary** of
> 27.50 pesetas.

I understand that as the times become more recent that the written language would become less archaic. But it begs the question, if all other instances of **27'50** were likewise referring to a **monthly salary**. It would only be logical that they did.

We previously ended up with DeepL suggesting it was:

- Constancy Allowance (Question: [1922](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39513/28260))
- Monthly Allowance (Question: [1930](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/39377/28260))

I welcome your clarifications.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1926 (note 2 of 2)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39530/28260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions

> Cumpliendo su compromiso en 31 de Agosto año marginal solicitó y le
> **fue concedido** por su **primer** Jefe otro por el tiempo de 4 años por **reunir** las
> condiciones prevenidas, incluso la de **utilidad** y como comprendido en
> la R. O. C de 11 de Agosto de 1920 (C. L. no. 195) pero en concepto de
> provisional hasta la aprobación **definitiva** del **Excmo**. **[Excelentísimo]** Sr.
> [Señor] **Dtor [Director]** Gral. [General] del Cuerpo. Dicho **compromiso** da
> **principio** en 1º de Septiembre de 1926 y lo terminar**á** en 31 de Agosto de
> 1930, **disfrutando** durante el mismo el premio mensual de 27’50 pesetas.
> Y en prueba de su conformidad, firma el interesado la presente **ante**
> el Jefe y testigos que suscriben.
>  El interesado = Miguel Torres
> Jiménez
>  Testigos =
>  El Gua [Guardia] 2º = **Manuel Ruiz** xxxx
>  El Gua [Guardia] 2º =
> **Alfonso Torres Laguna**
>  El Comandte **Mayor** = **Juan Egea Urraco**
> **Todo rubricado**
> **Es copia
>
> El Comandte Mayor.**

I can't make the top left word either. Something-**ños**.

---

Regarding your doubts about the translation

1. In Spanish in this context "presente" is an adjective. In this case the accompanying noun has been omitted "la presente (nota)". **Presente** refers to **the document itself**. It doesn't mean the same than present (noun) in English. I think that in English you can use both **this** and **this note** but it doesn't reflect exactly the Spanish version. I've got not an exact match to suggest. The **current**?
2. We saw in a previously linked bulletin that 27.50 is a **constancy reward** that is added to the salary monthly due to your ancestor's **labor seniority**. It's not the salary but a **bonus**. I'm not fully sure if bonus is synonym of constancy allowance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have updated the question with the translation and my observations.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I've updated my answer trying to solve your doubts

Comment: Thanks. 1. I understand you. 2. Then I must change this translation. If it is a *reward* then we tend to use the term *bonus*. So I'll change them to *monthly bonus* for consistency throughout.